# Angular Ui-router Resolve concept

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I was reading the docs of ui-router but I couldn't grasp the concept of resolves for controllers in each state. I am not able to figure out where should we use `resolve` and why the `controller` attached to a `state` is not enough (as we can inject any dependencies in it we want) ? 
I've tried going through docs and other tutorials several times but its quite confusing , Can someone please explain it with its real life application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A resolve is simply a value that is passed to the controller upon instantiation (which are used like an injected value). The neat thing about them is that if the value returned is a promise, the view/controller won't load until the promise has resolved.

The way you use them is by adding a `resolve` key to your route state, and returning the object you want injected into your controller (also naming it). For example:

```
.state('example', {
    url: '/page',
    templateUrl: 'sometemplate.html',
    controller: 'SomeCtrl',
    resolve: {
        injectionName: function(){
            // return a value or promise here to be injected as injectionName into your controller
        }
    }
});
```

Then inside your controller you simply add the resolve name to the controller injected values:

```
.controller('SomeCtrl', function($scope, injectionName){
    // do stuff with injectionName
});
```

Just note that if you do return a promise, the value that is injected is the **result** of the promise (not the promise itself). Also note that if the promise errors the view/controller will not load, and an error will be thrown. As @koox00 commented, this error will fail silently unless `$stateChangeErrorError` is handled (usually in your apps primary `run()` function).

---

So why would you use this? Well if not inferred from above, you do this usually when you want your view/controller to wait until some async process has completed before loading a particular state. This saves you from creating loaders or loading processes for every single view/controller, moving it to a simple definition of what needs to be loaded.

Comment: an error won't be caught though, but it will reject silently. you have to catch that manually on `$stateChangeError` event

Answer (score 3):

Imagine you want to create a modal and pass some data to it. I'm using the angular-ui-bootstrap modals for this example.

```
var openExampleModal = function () {

    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: "Modal.html",
        controller: "ModalController",
        size: "lg"
    });

    return modalInstance.result;
};
```

Now if you want to pass some data to this modal on initialization, you can either save it in your $rootScope or some data service, or you can use resolve to inject it into your controller directly without having to use anything else.

```
var openExampleModal = function (myData) {

    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: "Modal.html",
        controller: "ModalController",
        size: "lg",
        resolve: {
            sampleData: function () {
                return myData;
            }
        }
    });

    return modalInstance.result;
};
```

and in your controller you would have:

```
MyController.$inject = ["sampleData"];

function Mycontroller(sampleData) {
//You can access the data you passed on via sampleData variable now.
};
```

Resolve is used to inject your own custom objects into the controller, not for injecting dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

As said by Jean-Philippe you can use resolve if you want to load some data before switching to a certain state. Resolve waits and blocks until the data is arrived and only then the state transition is done.
It is an highly discussed topic whether using a resolve or loading the data on the fly within the controller. I would say: It depends on your use case :)

Further info from supercool todd motto: https://toddmotto.com/resolve-promises-in-angular-routes/